# How to solve "fatal error: clang/Frontend/LangStandard.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I am trying to install the code of [this git repo](https://github.com/spcl/haystack).

I follow the instructions in its README file, but during the `make` command, I always get this error:

```
pet.cc:73:10: fatal error: clang/Frontend/LangStandard.h: No such file or directory
   73 | #include <clang/Frontend/LangStandard.h>
```

So I figured I need to install Clang separately, so I followed the instructions [here](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-the-source-code-and-building-llvm).

The LLVM and Clang installation seems to work, but I still get the same error when calling `make`.

So how do I get the clang frontend headers?

Another strange thing that happens: When calling `./autogen.sh` as described in the repo, I get a lot of warnings like this

```
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
```

or this

```
Makefile.am:10: warning: source file 'source/arith/errors.c' is in a subdirectory,
Makefile.am:10: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
automake: warning: possible forward-incompatibility.
automake: At least a source file is in a subdirectory, but the 'subdir-objects'
automake: automake option hasn't been enabled.  For now, the corresponding output
automake: object file(s) will be placed in the top-level directory.  However,
automake: this behaviour will change in future Automake versions: they will
automake: unconditionally cause object files to be placed in the same subdirectory
automake: of the corresponding sources.
automake: You are advised to start using 'subdir-objects' option throughout your
automake: project, to avoid future incompatibilities.
```

Could this also indicate a problem?

Comment: What OS and compiler? Did you install LLVM in a default header search path, or elsewhere?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04. I did not specify where to install. According to `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=directory — Specify for directory the full pathname of where you want the LLVM tools and libraries to be installed (default /usr/local).` it should be in `/usr/local` but I cannot see it there...

Comment: Try installing again in verbose mode, see where it ends up installing.

Comment: `whereis clang` gives `clang: /usr/bin/clang /usr/lib/clang /usr/include/clang /usr/share/man/man1/clang.1.gz` and `whereis llvm` gives `llvm: /usr/include/llvm`.

Comment: The instructions are for ubuntu 18.04. 20.04 should not be really difficult, but you'll need to adapt things a bit. Edit the source and/or build files here and there.

Comment: @arnt Okay, but what exactly should I look out for when editing?

Comment: Well... your first problem is to find out why it needs LangStandard.h and how to get it. So you look at the source code and see if that offers a hint, and you try to see whether the file may now [have moved to a different package](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=LangStandard.h&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any), and think about what you see, and change something. Then you repeat for the next error message. It's just debugging. Ordinary programming work.

Comment: Alright, chaning the path in the include seems to help. Thanks @arnt. But now there are many errors of the kind of `error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘PragmaEndScopHandler’` among others. How should I go about these errors? Do I maybe need an older version of llvm?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to compile against a version of Clang that
is too recent.  The last version of Clang that had
`clang/Frontend/LangStandard.h` is version 9:

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-9.0.0/clang/include/clang/Frontend/LangStandard.h

Version 10 and later lack that file:

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/llvmorg-10.0.0/clang/include/clang/Frontend

In the github UI, you can change the tag used to view the sources using
the dropdown in the upper left, under the "Files" header.  I used that
(and binary search) to determine which version removed that file.

However, downgrading to Clang 9 still might not be old enough.  The repo
you are trying to compile, https://github.com/spcl/haystack, was last
updated in July 2019, just before Clang 8 was released, so my guess is
it was meant to be compiled with Clang 7, which happens to be the oldest version
on the
[Clang+LLVM releases page](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases?page=10).

In general, the Clang API changes substantially from major version to
major version, while retaining compatibility only from minor
version to minor version.  So you'll want to use the major version that is the
closest possible match.  Unfortunately there's no easy way besides trial
and error to figure out the right version if the authors of the client program
do not specify which version they used.  (After a quick look, I wasn't able to see anywhere they specify that.)